# SQL query is not inserting records in table when column values are equal

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute this query but it is not working. whenever i try to put same equal values to any two or more input variables out of total 8, the SQL query does not execute.

php file:

```
include './config.php';

$counter = 0;
// these are my total 8 input variables
$INDEX_NUMBER           =  "43385";
$STATION_NAME           =  "NA";
$YEAR                   =  "2020";
$MONTH                  =  "12";
$DATE                   =  "18";
$Ir                     =  "3";                                     
$RAIN_24HOURS_ACTUAL    =  "NA";
$RTRTRTRT               =  "NA";

                                    
$sql_rain_2 ="INSERT INTO `only_rainfall_2020` (`INDEX_NUMBER`, `STATION_NAME`, `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `DATE`, `Ir`, `DAILY`, `SEASONALLY_SYNOP`) SELECT * FROM (SELECT '$INDEX_NUMBER', '$STATION_NAME', '$YEAR', '$MONTH', '$DATE', '$Ir', '$RAIN_24HOURS_ACTUAL', '$RTRTRTRT') AS tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT `INDEX_NUMBER`, `STATION_NAME`, `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `DATE`, `Ir`, `DAILY`, `SEASONALLY_SYNOP` FROM `only_rainfall_2020` WHERE `INDEX_NUMBER` = '$INDEX_NUMBER' AND `STATION_NAME` = '$STATION_NAME' AND `YEAR` = '$YEAR' AND `MONTH` = '$MONTH' AND `DATE` = '$DATE' AND `Ir` = '$Ir' AND `DAILY` = '$RAIN_24HOURS_ACTUAL' AND `SEASONALLY_SYNOP` = '$RTRTRTRT') LIMIT 1";


if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql_rain_2)) {
    $counter++;
    }

$array = array("rain1"=>$counter, "rain2"=>"yogi");
echo json_encode($array);
```

mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE `only_rainfall_2020` (
  `SERIAL` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SUB_DIVISION_NUMBER` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `SUB_DIVISION_NAME` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `INDEX_NUMBER` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `STATION_NAME` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `YEAR` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `MONTH` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `DATE` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `Ir` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `DAILY` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `MONTHLY` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `SEASONALLY_SYNOP` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `SEASONALLY_CALCULATE` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `ANNUALLY` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `COMMENT` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `MANUALLY_EDIT_VALUE` varchar(14) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `only_rainfall_2020`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`SERIAL`);

ALTER TABLE `only_rainfall_2020`
  MODIFY `SERIAL` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

Please point out my mistake.
After many attempts i could not find my mistake.

let me clear it again:
I am trying to insert data for 8 columns into a table which has total 16 columns. In my table, one column is for serial number which is auto incremental, seven are blank columns and eight are the columns in which i am inserting data. I am leaving seven blank column for future work with no default values. the condition for inserting data for these eight column: any row should not exist with same data for these eight columns which i am going to insert. when i give different values for these eight columns than query is successful and data inserted but when i put same values for any two or more columns than query does not execute.

this is successful:

```
$INDEX_NUMBER           =  "43385";
$STATION_NAME           =  "DELHI";
$YEAR                   =  "2020";
$MONTH                  =  "12";
$DATE                   =  "18";
$Ir                     =  "3";                                     
$RAIN_24HOURS_ACTUAL    =  "NA";
$RTRTRTRT               =  "20";
```

But when i put any two values same the query does not execute.

Failed with error: (#1060 - Duplicate column name 'NA')

```
$INDEX_NUMBER           =  "43385";
$STATION_NAME           =  "NA";
$YEAR                   =  "2020";
$MONTH                  =  "12";
$DATE                   =  "18";
$Ir                     =  "3";                                     
$RAIN_24HOURS_ACTUAL    =  "NA";
$RTRTRTRT               =  "NA";
```

And yes there are warnings for like:
Warning: #1364 Field 'SUB_DIVISION_NUMBER' doesn't have a default value

But i will add values in these columns later.

Comment: It strikes me that all of your fields are `NOT NULL` and none of them have any defaults, yet you do not specify data for all fields in your `INSERT` statement.  You should probably look at error messages from the database (you did not mention anything about errors).

Comment: it says #1060 - Duplicate column name 'NA'

Comment: yes, many fields are null and don't have default values but i will add data to them with another query in future.

Comment: You should add clarifying information like that to the question, not in comments. Also you can not insert data into a table without specifying what goes into `NOT NULL` fields that have no defaults.  I'm thinking you have a quoting issue, or you're running into an issue with trying to use a query designed for a non-MySQL database on MySQL. I don't know why you insist on quoting everything (even things, like table names, that does not need quoting). Did you transfer the SQL over from some other database engine?

Comment: Thanks, I am new so could not aware of proper ways. I added more information at the end. I was able to add data without specifying what goes into NOT NULL fields that have no defaults. I am using quoting because i am using this query into a loop and everytime i have to change values for each loop. For this plateform i shortened and simplyfied my php code into a simple one.